# How do I set the 'type' of the main Vue 3 'app' variable

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to implement a small typescript Vue3 app as a training exercise. I am making pretty good progress, but have run into a hurdle. Some advice from those more knowledgeable than me would be appreciated.

I have been setting up authorisations using firebase and am implementing route guards. These work, except in the case where the user types the new route directly in the address bar. In this case it seems to recreate teh app before it has the information regarding the looged in user. It therefore thinks the user is null, and renders the Login Page. So I am advised to implement the following.

**main.ts**

```js
import App from './App.vue'
import { createApp, App as Application } from 'vue'
import router from './router'

import { projectAuth } from './firebase/config'
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'

let app: Application

onAuthStateChanged(projectAuth, () => {
  if (!app) {
    app = createApp(App)     // type error on 'app'
      .use(router)
      .mount('#app')
  }
})
```

It works as a pure Javascript implementation, but throws a type error in typescript.

How can I define the type of **app** in the above code?

I have tried several variations, all ineffective, including:

```
let app: typeof App 
let app: App<Element>
let app: typeof Application
```

I guess it is something simple, but as a typescript newbie it eludes me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import `App` type from `vue`, rename it to something like `Application` to avoid  collapsing with your `App` component, and then annotate your `app` with type `Application`:

```
import { createApp, App as Application } from 'vue'
let app: Application;

onAuthStateChanged(projectAuth, () => {
  if (!app) {
    app = createApp(App).use(router)
    app.mount('#app')       // do not chain mount after createApp
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom. Tried your suggestion, but still get a type error on 'app = createApp(App)'. I have updated the orriginal code.

Comment: You need to remove `.mount` from the chain and move it to a new line.  See my code.

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks - sorry - I did not twig to that difference. Works a treat now